# web api spa the view at '~/index.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>

Tags: asp.net, razor

Hi Using John Papas codecamper as an example, My web api spa has index.cshtml at the root folder with a few cshtml pages in a sub folder called views. There is no web.config in the views folder

When I put

```
@RenderPage("Views/welcome.cshtml")*
```

in the index.cshtml I get error

"The view at '~/index.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage."

If I don't have renderpage then the index.cshtml loads ok. What am I missing? Does the codecamper require Require.js or something to use @RenderPage. I am not routing index through a controller and don't want to .

Sorry am aware this is a common problem but can't get it to render using any suggestions on web.

Comment: You are probably missing the mvc staff in you web config. Check the web.config from a file new web application with mvc setup upfront.

Comment: what is mvc staff? The web.configs seem to be the same, not missing anything.

Comment: Also the default spa template in vs2015 creates what looks to me like an mvc app with controllers for each view. I don't see any difference between it and a standard asp.net mvc app. I thought a spa loads one main page first then uses javascript like Sammy.js to show and hide partial pages in html5 sections as required?

Comment: After more trial and error I believe the issue is because those pages in the views were not partial pages and I should be using @Html.Partial("_Welcome") to show them.